# Sequelize can not import a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

In expressJs project, I try to use sequelize to interact with database.

This is my model/user.js :

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    sequelize.define('user', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        password: DataTypes.STRING
    })
}
```

And this is models/index.js :

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) =>
      file !== 'index.js'
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    var a = path.join(__dirname, file);
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  })

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

The problem is in this line

```
const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
```

Which returns undefine to model variable.

What did I miss here? I appreciate any hint?

Whole code on Github : [here](https://github.com/peymannj/VueApp/tree/master/server)

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be because of a missing return

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', { // Missing return
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        password: DataTypes.STRING
    })
}
```

Change to

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        password: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    return User;
}
```